# How can I append dynamic variables to div with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some difficulty getting this to work. What I want to do is take dynamic variables from the onclick and place them into a div I am appending to another div in the document. Since each each item will have variables associated from a database query, I figured populating the buildTicket() variables from the database would be easier.

I know I'm doing something wrong. I just can't figure out what.

If you have a better way, I'm all ears.

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {
buildTicket = function(eventname,ticketprice,venueid,userid) {
    $(".ticketbtn").click(function(){
      $(".ticketwindow").append("<div class='ticket'>" + eventname + " - " +     eventprice + "</div>");
    });
}
});
</script>
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="ticketbtn" onclick="buildTicket('Some Show','12.00','1','2');">
        <img src="assets/images/tixicon.png" alt=""> <div class="eventname">Some Show</div>
        <div class="ticketprice">Adult - 12.00    </div>
    </div>

<div id="ticketwindow">

</div>
```

Can someone help me figure this out?

(sorry for the code formatting. Still trying to figure out how to use stackoverflow's forms properly.)

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: you dont have an element with class `ticketwindow` in your html

Comment: You have an anon function inside a `document.ready` function, which is repetitive. Additionally, your anon function ends in a single brace, instead of `(function() { }())`

Comment: You are attaching multiple click functions because you have a repetitive loop in your function. Remove the inline onclick

Comment: You need to put the values into variables.  Then run a `$.each` function for each variable.

Comment: @NappingRabbit - There I added the ticketwindow element.

Comment: @Sergio - I need to be able to click it more than once. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @JoeNobody, i mean that in your html you call the function -> the function ads one more click listener to the same class that will fire on next click -> on next click you add one more... it's a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `$(function() {` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() {` so you only need one of them.

Secondly, you don't need to use the `onclick` attribute if you are binding to `click()` with jQuery, or vice versa.

If you just use the `onclick` attribute, then you can remove your document ready handler, and your `click()` binding, all together and simply define the `buildTicket()` function.

Thirdly, the `eventprice` variable is misnamed in `buildTicket()`.

Here is a working fiddle, using jQuery to bind to the `click` event of your button div. http://jsfiddle.net/BdJAL/

Comment: So far so good. Very nice indeed. So, by doing it this way, how would I add the other variables (venuid, userid) to the appended stuff. I'm actually using those variables, and the current date and time to create a unique number.

Comment: There's a number of ways to do it. You could put them in hidden divs within each button and use the same method to retrieve them as shown in my fiddle. Would that be what you were after?

Comment: ... or store each ticket type as an object in your javascript, which is slightly more advanced to implement, but it would make your code more concise and reusable.

Comment: Quick example of one way to abstract your tickets into an object. http://jsfiddle.net/EC8y6/

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the onClick listener on click of your button.

If you must use the onClick element attribute then the following code will work although you should become familiar with the principles of [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var buildTicket = function(eventname,ticketprice,venueid,userid) {
        $("#ticketwindow").append("<div class='ticket'>" + eventname + " - " + eventprice + "</div>");
    });
});
```

Comment: I figured I need the onclick="buildTicket('Some Show','12.00','1','2');" because the variables change for each "ticket". Is there a better way?

Comment: Assuming that the ticket data source is a JSON file, I would use the jQuery method [`.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to build an array of 'ticket' objects. For each of these I would render a `<div class="ticketbtn" data-eventname="x" data-ticketprice="12.00" data-venueid="1" data-userid="2"></div>` and bind a generic click event handler to them all.

Answer (score 0):

I quote from your question:
"I figured populating the buildTicket() variables from the database would be easier."

If you want to get hold of database data in your JavaScript how about making an HTTP request to get it. Obviously, you could do this in the normal XJAX way using XMLHttpRequest:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp
Or you could call up some server side code to produce JSON for you and reference it in a <script> tag e.g.
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jsonFromServerSideCode.jsp"></script>